# How to get the values of the ListAdapter to a workbook cell

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am creating a workbook from my app. I get the Arraylist of data from sqlite and then use a ListAdapter to view it. I can save to the workbook just fine. The rows show the data but what they show is the raw data from the query like Personfirstname= John, and Personlastname = Doe all in one cell. That is not what I want. What I want is too see John in cell 1, Doe in cell 2 also Jane in row 2 of cell 2 and doe in cell 2 of row 2. I know I need to do something with my ListAdapter I just don't know what to do.

Here is my code(I'm using apache.poi jar)

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = controller .getAllpersons(value1,value2);

ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(Persons.this, test, R.layout.rowsales,
new String[] { "NamesId", "personfirstname","personlastname }, 
new int[] {R.id.NamesId, R.id.personfirstname,R.id.personlastname});


for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {

Row row2 = sheet1.createRow((short) i+3);
c = row2.createCell(0);
System.out.println(test.get(i));
c.setCellValue(test.get(i).toString());
c.setCellStyle(s);
}
```

Comment: Where do `ListAdapter` and `SimpleAdapter` come from? And how are you storing the firstname and lastname into the hash?

Comment: They are for my ListView. That works fine. I'm trying to get what's in ListView to the cells in my workbook. My code gets the correct info. The problem is it prints the column name like personfirstname="john" when I just want "john".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't actually with the POI code (mostly)...

Your problem are with these two lines:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = controller .getAllpersons(value1,value2);

c.setCellValue(test.get(i).toString());
```

Your variable `test` is a list of hash maps. The maps will be indexed by key, and the things you want will be in the value. However, you're then ignoring the map lookup, and just fetching the whole lot + turning into a string.

Assuming that the `String[]` you pass to `SimpleAdapter` is the keys of the map, then what you'd need to do is:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet s1 = wb.createSheet();
for (int i=0; i<test.size(); i++) {
    String firstname = 
    Row r = s1.createRow(i);

    Map<String,String> personData = test.get(i);

    Cell fn = r.createCreateCell(0, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    fn.setCellValue(data.get("personfirstname"));

    Cell ln = r.createCreateCell(1, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    ln.setCellValue(data.get("personlastname"));
}
```

Comment: I made a few changes like Map to HashMap and firstname String was unnecessary but your answer was very helpful and right. Thank You.